# Getting "TypeError: pwd: expected bytes, got str" when extracting zip file with password

Tags: python, zip

I want to unzip a specific named file located in a specific directory.

The name of the file = `happy.zip`.
The location = `C:/Users/desktop/Downloads`.

I want to extract all the files to `C:/Users/desktop/Downloads`(the same location)

I tried:

```
import zipfile
import os
in_Zip = r"C:/Users/desktop/Downloads/happy.zip"
outDir = r"C:/Users/desktop/Downloads"
z = zipfile.ZipFile(in_Zip, 'r')
z.extractall(outDir, pwd='1234!')
z.close
```

But I got:

> "TypeError: pwd: expected bytes, got str"

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: when i wrote this, it says
"TypeError: pwd: expected bytes, got str"

Comment: z.extractall(outDir, pwd=b'1234!')

Answer (score 7):

In Python 2: `'1234!'` = byte string

In Python 3: `'1234!'` = unicode string

Assuming you are using Python 3, you need to either use `b'1234!'` or encode the string to get byte string using `str.encode()` this is useful if you have the password saved as a string `passwd = '1234!'` then you can use:

```
z.extractall(outDir, pwd=passwd.encode())
```

or use byte string directly:

```
z.extractall(outDir, pwd=b'1234!')
```

Comment: Thank you for ur kind answer. Now I got through this!

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find it useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this will only work if the zip file has been encrypted using the "Zip legacy encryption" option when setting up the password.